# not able to restrict the mysql AURORA access from a specific host.ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'10.1.21.54'

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'10.1.21.54' (using password: YES)
Not able to restrict the MYSQL remote access from a specific host on Aurora db cluster

Answer (score 0):

Restricting a DB user with a specific host 'username'@'hostname' is currently not supported in Aurora Serverless.  So this is a reason why i was receiving the above error message
No ETA yet by AWS that when it will be done, but they are working on it.